# Spinner anidados con Android extrayendo datos desde una base de datos externa

Tags: android, sql, json, spinner

Debo de crear tres `spinners` en Android:

- Estados
- Municipios
- Localidades

Los spinner que les presento funcionan, me extraen los datos y me los muestran en los spinner correspondientes, lo que aun no logro conseguir es pasar la clave `cveEstados` de la clase `getEsatdos()` a la clase `getMunicipios` para enviarlo como parametro al archivo php `listMunicipios` y me muestre solo los municipios de ese estado. Como le podría hacer, los metodos que he visto en internet no me han funcionado.

## Adaptador ItemEstados.java

```
public class ItemsEstados {

private String id;
private String nombre;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

}

## Clase java getEstados()

```
public void getEstados(){

        String Url_Address = "http://xxxxx/Conexion/listEstados.php";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url_Address, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    estadosList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        ItemsEstados estado = new ItemsEstados();
                        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        estado.setId(obj.getString("id"));
                        estado.setNombre(obj.getString("nombre"));
                        estadosList.add(estado);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < estadosList.size(); i++){

                        estado.add(estadosList.get(i).getId()+" "+estadosList.get(i).getNombre());
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(DatosPersonales.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, estado);
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinnerEstados.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

## Archivo PHP listEstados

```
<?php 
      include 'conexion.php';
      $sql = "SELECT cveEstado, nomEstado FROM Estados";
      $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
      $result = array();

      while($rs = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $id = $rs["cveEstado"];
            $nombre = $rs["nomEstado"];

            $response = array();
            $response["id"] = $id;
            $response["nombre"] = $nombre;

            array_push($result, $response);
      }

      echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

## Adaptador ItemMunicipios

```
public class ItemsMunicipios {

private String id;
private String nombre;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

}

## Clase java getMunicipios()

```
public void getMunicipios(){

        String Url_Address = "http://xxxxxx/Conexion/listMunicipios.php";
        final String claveEstado = "01";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url_Address, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    municipiosList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        ItemsMunicipios municipio = new ItemsMunicipios();
                        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        municipio.setId(obj.getString("id"));
                        municipio.setNombre(obj.getString("nombre"));
                        municipiosList.add(municipio);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < municipiosList.size(); i++){

                        municipio.add(municipiosList.get(i).getId()+" "+municipiosList.get(i).getNombre());
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DatosPersonales.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, municipio);
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinnerMunicipios.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("claveEstado", claveEstado);
                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
```

## Archivo PHP listMunicipios

```
<?php
     include 'conexion.php';
     $cveE = $_POST['claveEstado'];

     if ($cveE != null) {

         $sql = "SELECT cveMunicipio, nomMunicipio FROM Municipios WHERE 
         cveEstado='$cveE'";

         $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
         $result = array();

         while($rs = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

               $id = $rs["cveMunicipio"];
               $nombre = $rs["nomMunicipio"];

               $response = array();
               $response["id"] = $id;
               $response["nombre"] = $nombre;

               array_push($result, $response);
        }

        echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);   
 } else {

 echo "Campo vacío";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: y qué has intentado?

Comment: Lo he intentado con volley al extraer los datos y cargarlos en los spinner, si me cargan los datos pero son todos los datos no de forma anidada

Comment: Muestra el código que has hecho, y dónde no realiza las acciones como necesitas, para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Desconozco desarrollo para android, y también desconozco como tienes almacenada la información. En términos generales, primero tendrías que cargar el spinner de estados. Una vez que el usuario seleccione el estado, lo usarías como filtro para tu segundo spinner, y en ese momento cargarías municipios. Una vez el usuario seleccione el municipio, tendrías que cargar el spinner de localidades, con el municipio seleccionado como filtro. ¡Mucha suerte!

Comment: Como podría pasar la variable getId de estados a la clase getMunicipios para enviarlo como parametro y que solo me muestre los municipios de ese estado